# Disregarding Value of Zero on a Cell when Comparing for > 0

Tags: excel, vba

would like to ask if there is a way to disregard 0 value when comparing?

to be specific i need to compare a value greater than zero if they are equal..and if so, a msgbox "" will appear ... to be honest i am not knowledgeable so i just used if statement... and need to compare 7 cells... i have to redundantly use if then statement for ever possible 0 and non zero combinations. (which ofc. alot)

example all zeroes will be neglected, if for instance cellA = 2 and CellB = 0 and CellC = 2 then it will show a msgbox because cellA an cellC is > 0 and have the same value(which is correct). but when i turned cellA = 0 and CellB = 0 and Cell3 = 0 ...it still showing a msgbox.. i was hoping that when all the cells turned 0 it will neglect the condition "if A = B, B = C then appear msgbox" but will consider the condition if it is  > 0.

Advance thanks

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you can post your code and some sample data in table format. Why not just sum the cells and evaluate it the sum is > 0?

Comment: Get the average, and compare every cell with this average. If the average is 0 to start with, return false.

Comment: well i can do that, but i can't, since if i input 0 ..that individual cell or lets say cell A =1, cell B = 0, cell C = 0 .. the msgbox will still appear and when i do the averaging i will still get a value (it will only work if all cells is 0 right??) and some cells equal to zeroes will still popout the msgbox. is there any alternaatives?...since i will have random numbers on multiple cells having 0 & > 0 in it. it will disregard that 0 value. thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you've tried and some sample data please.  Might also be worth having a read of [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub msgBx()
    'Set some vars
    Dim sourceArr, dict As Object, j As Long, i As Long
    
    'get data in memory = array
    sourceArr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value2
    
    'build a dict to compare quickly
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
    For j = 1 To UBound(sourceArr, 2) 'traverse source
        dict(sourceArr(1, j)) = Empty
    Next j
    
    'check if key exists in dict and copy data
    For j = 1 To UBound(sourceArr)
        For i = 1 To UBound(sourceArr, 2)
            If sourceArr(j, i) <> 0 And dict.Exists(sourceArr(j, i)) Then
                MsgBox "gotya"
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```